# Is there a way to read token address from the command line Hardhat script RSK

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I have a [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) script
that queries the [RIF token](https://developers.rsk.co/rif/token/) balance
on [Rootstock](https://developers.rsk.co/).
However the RIF address is hardcoded in my script:
​

```js
const rifTokenAddress = '0x2aCc95758f8b5F583470bA265Eb685a8f45fC9D5';
​
async function main() {
  const erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt(
    ['function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint)'],
    rifTokenAddress.toLowerCase(),
  );
  const walletAddress = (await ethers.getSigner(0)).address;
  const rifBalance = await erc20.balanceOf(walletAddress);
  console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(rifBalance));
}
​
main();
```

​
Now I am using this command to run the script:
​

```bash
npx hardhat run scripts/balances.js --network rskmainnet
```

​
I would like to be able to specify
a token address in the command line like this:
​

```bash
npx hardhat run scripts/balances.js --network rskmainnet --token 0x2d919f19D4892381d58EdEbEcA66D5642ceF1A1F
```

​
Is there a way to modify Hardhat script
so that it could read token address from
the command line,
similar to how I select the network with `--network` parameter?
​
For reference, this is my `hardhat.config.js` file:
​

```js
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');
const { mnemonic } = require('./.secret.json');
​
const accounts = {
  mnemonic,
  path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
};
​
module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.9',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      accounts,
    },
    rskmainnet: {
      chainId: 30,
      url: 'https://public-node.rsk.co/',
      accounts,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

One quick solution that I can think of is, put your npx hardhat command as a script in your package.json.

```
"hardhat-runner": "npx hardhat run --network rskmainnet scripts/balances.js"
```

Now you can invoke this using the following command. Now pass your arg 'token'.

```
npm run hardhat-runner --token=0x2d919f19D4892381d58EdEbEcA66D5642ceF1A1F
```

In your js code, you will get this as env variable.

```
process.env.npm_config_token
```

IMO, hardhat does not accept custom args hence passing any args directly will lead to HH308 error. This may change in future though.

Note: This solution has been tested on NPM 7 only.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it with Hardhat *scripts*.
This is because scripts only allow Hardhat's built in CLI parameters
(including `--network`),
but does not allow you to define your own custom CLI parameters.

However it's easy to accomplish by converting your script to a *task*,
which does allow you to define your own custom CLI parameters.

See the [Hardhat task docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/create-task).

To address your specific question:

Create a file `tasks/balance.js` and copy-paste the following task definition:

```js
const { task } = require('hardhat/config');

const rifTokenAddress = '0x2aCc95758f8b5F583470bA265Eb685a8f45fC9D5';

module.exports = task('balance', 'Displays token balance')
  .addOptionalParam('token', 'ERC20 token name')
  .setAction(async ({ token }) => {
    const erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt(
      ['function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint)'],
      token?.toLowerCase() || rifTokenAddress.toLowerCase(),
    );
    const walletAddress = (await ethers.getSigner(0)).address;
    const erc20Balance = await erc20.balanceOf(walletAddress);
    console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(erc20Balance));
  });
```

Note that the above code is based on your original *Hardhat script*,
and has been adapted to convert it into a *Hardhat task*;
plus add parameters.

This code defines a `balance` task with one optional `--token` parameter which accepts ERC20 token address.
If `--token` is unspecified,
its default value is `rifTokenAddress`.

Import the task at the top of the `hardhat.config.js`:

```js
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');
require('./tasks/balance.js');
```

Now you can query token balances from the command line like this:

```bash
# queries default token balance
npx hardhat balance
  --network rsktestnet
```

or like this:

```bash
# queries specified token balance
npx hardhat balance
  --network rsktestnet \
  --token 0x19f64674D8a5b4e652319F5e239EFd3bc969a1FE
```

Comment: nitpick: `0x2aCc95758f8b5F583470bA265Eb685a8f45fC9D5` is the address of RIF token on RSK Mainnet (chain ID = 30), not RSK Testnet.

Comment: Good catch, [@bguiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194982/bguiz), thank you! On the Rootstock Testnet its address is `0x19f64674D8a5b4e652319F5e239EFd3bc969a1FE`